# Constructing Regular expression that generates a given languge

Tags: string, expression, computation

This is an example ginen in my textbook "`Introduction to theory of Computation`". 
Given that the alphabet `∑ as{0,1}`,

```
{w|every 0 in w is followed by atleast one 1}}
```

a regular expression for it is shown as `(01+)*. 1+` means only a single instance of 1. Now what I understand is that `(01+)*` would mean string like `0101010101010101....` what if I have a string `11111101 or 011111111` or just 1
These string do fulfill the given criteria. But the regular expression `(01+)*` will not generate them.

```
Secondly for `{w|w starts and ends with same symbol}` the expression is given as `0∑*0 U 1∑*1 U 0 U 1.`
```

As far as I have learnt the union of two things means either first one, or second one **OR BOTH**. If I take a string 01110 for `0∑*0` and another string for `10001 1∑*1` and then take union of these two `0111010001`the union string `DOESNOT` start and end with same symbol. Does it mean that union cannot combine both or the expression is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

`1+` means 'one or more 1s'. Therefore, it generates 1, 11, 111, and so on. So the regular expression `(01+)*` actually generates the strings in which "every 0 is followed by one or more 1s and the first symbol in the string is not a 1".

To get `{w|every 0 in w is followed by atleast one 1}` the regular expression would be slightly different. It would be `1*(01+)*`

In the second question, what you have taken is concatenation. `01110` concatenated with `10001` is `0111010001`. Union of two sets is a set containing all the elements of both sets